# How to shape sheet metal like Willys hood latch?

Tags: metal-folding

I am want to produce Willys' hood latches like links below

[Hood latch link 1](https://www.kaiserwillys.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x560/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/7/6/7601v_enlarged.jpg)

[Hood latch link 2](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31gj6IUCyRL._SX425_.jpg)

[Hood latch link 3](https://picclick.com/Jeep-Willys-MB-GPW-windshield-to-hood-latch-271115518868.html)

What kind of metal shaping process is this? 
Even I could not figure the mold out.

Comment: Most of the flat bits are stamped, but with 2 or 3 operations at a guess...

Comment: Why don't you just buy some, it will be faster and cheaper !!!

Comment: because i am considering mass production of whole body of CJ jeep and include these ones too.